# How can I calculate the difference between two named columns in a huge CSV file, then save the results to a second CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, bigdata

I have a CSV file containing almost 200 million rows (gigabytes of data). It has only 5 columns. I want to iterate over the data and do simple calculations, first between columns, but then between rows.

Sample data:

```
DateTime,Width,Length,Count,Age
01.01.2010 00:00:00,0.55,0.25,1,4
07.02.2010 00:00:01,0.53,0.28,2,3
21.02.2010 00:00:01,0.55,0.25,2,3
20.03.2010 00:00:01,0.55,0.25,1,3
09.05.2010 00:00:02,0.55,0.25,4,7
11.05.2010 00:00:02,0.5,0.3,3,5
```

I am using Python with Pandas to read the data in chunks, but I am not sure how to access each column in each row to perform basic arithmetic.

Here is my currently not working python:

```py
import pandas as pd

file_in = r"B:\Users\user\Documents\huge-dataset.csv"
file_out = r"B:\Users\user\Documents\aggregate.csv"

data = pd.read_csv(file_in, chunksize=100000)

for idx, chunk in enumerate(data):
    for row in chunk:
        print("row: ", row)
        diff = row[1] - row[2]
        data_out.append([row[0],diff])
        if row[0] == 0:
            prevrow = row
        else:
            rowdiff = row[1] - prevrow[1]

pd.write_csv(file_out, data_out)
```

I want to use the column names, for example:

`ratio = row['Width']/row['Length']`

I then want to compare each row with previous rows, for example:

`width_diff = row['width'] - prev_row['width']`

Any pointers/corrections?

Comment: If you can load data into one chunk, then you can do `data_out = data.diff()`.

Comment: If by "one chunk" you mean the entire dataset - impossible. It is too big to read the whole file into memory at once. This is the reason for chunking - memory management.

Comment: Still, you can do in chunk with just `data.diff()`. You just need to handle the first rows of the chunks carefully. Also, you can't keep writing on the `file_out`, because each `write_csv` command will overwrite the content of thefile.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the name of the DataFrame is `df`. For calculating the first formula, you can easily write :

```
ratio = df['Width']/df['Length']
```

If you want to store it as a new column in your DataFrame, you can write :

```
df['ratio'] = df['Width']/df['Length']
```

For the second formula you can use [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html)() function.

```
width_diff = df['Width'].diff()
```

Finally for storing the DataFrame into a file you can use `to_csv()` function. There is no `write_csv()` function in pandas.

```
df.to_csv(file_out)
```

Comment: I will try your suggestions out and see if they work for me.

Comment: Ok, let me know if these suggestions helped you